# org-capture frame with no splits

Tags: frames, org-capture

I want to be able to launch a new emacsclient and issue org-capture in it. I have created this simple function:

```
(defun make-orgcapture-frame ()
  "Create a new frame and run org-capture."
  (interactive)
  (make-frame '((name . "zorg") (width . 180) (height . 160)
                (top . 400) (left . 300)
                ))
(select-frame-by-name "zorg")
(delete-other-windows)
(org-capture)
)
```

i then launch it with this command

```
emacsclient -n -e '(make-capture-frame)'
```

while this works it always opens in a split view where an old buffer from any current emacs frame i have open appears.

is there anyway i can make the org-capture buffer take the whole frame?

Comment: I can start you on your journey, but not get you over the finish line because there are too many different org- versions out there -- some old, some new.  As to the org-mode that ships with Emacs 26.1, the function `org-mks` calls `org-switch-to-buffer-other-window` when creating the initial buffer with choices to select a template.  The question does not indicate whether we are interested in only the initial window that displays choices of templates, or the window layout when a template has been selected ....  That function calls `(org-no-popups (apply 'switch-to-buffer-other-window args))`.

Comment: Here is how to trace what is happening ... `M-x find-function RET org-capture RET`.  Now move down a few lines and find where it calls `org-capture-select-template` -- place the cursor somewhere on that word and type `M-x find-function`, which will have a default value of the `org-capture-select-template` -- use the default and hit return and get transported to that function.  Now, move the cursor down a few lines and find where it calls `org-mks` -- place the cursor on that function and type `M-x find-function`, which will default to `org-mks` ... hit return and go to `org-mks`....

Comment: Here is an example to get you started -- this temporarily makes `org-switch-to-buffer-other-window` behave as if it were actually `switch-to-buffer` -- we load `org` and `cl` to ensure the functions `org-switch-to-buffer-other-window` and `cl-letf` are available:  `(progn (require 'org) (require 'cl) (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'org-switch-to-buffer-other-window) #'switch-to-buffer)) (org-capture)))`

Comment: According to the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Frames.html), `make-frame` creates a frame displaying a current buffer. I'm not sure why `delete-other-windows` fails to kill the other buffer then.